# How to hide keypad in android after pressing home button

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-keypad

I am showing a list with messages and each message's row has a comment button.When i click on comment button opens a comment box with edit text and button for submitting the comment.When comment box appears on screen keypad also appears for entering text.If i pressed home button before entering text then application goes background but keypad remains on screen.This is the thing irritating me.For custom list i am using a custom adapter and code for comment box is written in that adapter.I tried using

inputmgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtComments.getWindowToken(), 0);

but it is not working. So how i can hide this keypad programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/1904479. Hope you are not testing it in Android version 4.1.

Comment: I am testing it on 4.2. I can tried this but not works.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME` can NOT be intercepted. You can hide the keypad `inputmgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);` in `onStop()` method of your activity.

It does not require token from focused view `editText`.

Comment: @Nava2011's answer is better. For this one you can create a method in the adapter class and call it from the activity.

Comment: EditText is returning null.

Comment: edited the answer, check now. Call it directly from `onStop()` of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

please use this method to hide soft keyboard.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity context) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow().getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }
```

Comment: when you press home button just call this method only i think it will work.;-) can you please update your code when you want to hide soft keyboard?

Comment: I am calling this method in onPause().

Comment: I think you have to call this method when you press home button.then soft keyboard will hide.